# Windows phone web app native date picker

Tags: windows-phone-7, web-applications, cordova, datepicker

I am working  on phonegap web app for windows mobile. I used date field for get user input.

```
<input type="date" name="departure" id="text-from" value=""  novalidate="true" />
```

I tried with Modernizr,

```
$(function() {
    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes['date']) {
    $('input[type=date]').datepicker();
    }
    });
```

It is working with IE 9 browser, but not in windows phone simulator. How can i show native date picker in windows phone for web apps.

Comment: IE9 (the desktop version) is not the same as IE 9 Mobile (the Windows Phone version). Some things may not work and you need to create workarounds for WP as a special platform.